# C++ Creating array based on what functions were called

Tags: c++

For example lets say I have this simple code:

```
using namespace std;
char re = 'y';
void mult(int one, int two)
{
    int mult = 1;
    mult = one * two;
    cout << mult << endl;
}

void add(int one, int two)
{
    int add = 0;
    add = one + two;
    cout << add << endl;
}

void rep(int one, int two)
{
}

void ask()
{
    int re;
    cout << "do you want return to the menu? (1/2)" << endl;
    cin >> re;
}

int main()
{
    char re;
    int one;
    int two;

    cout << "enter the number one:" << endl;
    cin >> one;
    cout << "enter the number two:" << endl;
    cin >> two;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Multiply - 1" << endl;
    cout << "Add      - 2" << endl;
    cout << "Reprint  - 3" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    int menu;
    if (re == 'y')
    {
        cout << "select the function ";
        cin >> menu;
        switch (menu)
        {
            case 1:
                mult(one, two);
                ask();
                break;
            case 2:
                add(one, two);
                ask();
                break;
            case 3:
                rep(one, two);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "no such thing" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }

    else if (re != 'y')
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need a way function rep to print out the answer of previously called functions.

For example if function mult was called it should print mult answer, IF mult and add were called then it should print mult and add function answers, if only add then only add.

I was thinking about creating a zero array and changing it whether function one or two was called out, and then somehow call the answers out. But no idea how to do it.

Comment: Why not put this as part of the switch cases?

Comment: Your `ask` function should return some kind of status or response to the caller; otherwise, it is pointless.

Comment: In your `main` function, the `re` variable is uninitialized before the `if` statement.

Comment: You don't need the `if` with the `else` clause.  The `else` alone means `re != 'y'`.

Comment: Coding Guidelines:  prefer not to name variables the same as the functions.  Use a thesaurus if necessary.  You could use `sum` in your `add` function and `product` in your `mult` function.

Comment: You are confusing the reader and yourself by having `re` as a global variable and another `re` as a local variable in `main`.  They are not the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global variable.

```
int last_result = 0;
void mult(int a, int b)
{
  last_result = a * b;
  std::cout << last_result << std::endl;
}

void add(int a, int b)
{
  last_result = a + b;
  std::cout << last_result << std::endl;
}

void rep()
{
  std::cout << "Last result: " << last_result << std::endl;
}
```

You could also have the `mult` and `add` functions return a result and store the result in `main` (and pass it to the `rep` function).

You could pass the `last_result` variable by reference to the `add` and `mult` functions.